# I want to install kivy but cmd is not responding accordingly. How to fix it?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, kivy

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Sairish>python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv

C:\Users\Sairish>python -m virtualenv kivy_venv

C:\Users\Sairish>pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\sairish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:\Users\Sairish>
```

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv?

Comment: can you please tell how to activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after creating the environment **kivy_venv**, do this in the cmd.

```
C:\Users\Sairish>cd kivy_venv/Scripts
```

then do this

```
C:\Users\Sairish\kivy_venv\Scripts>activate
```

to activate the virtual the environment. then continue the installation process from the number 2. point. Click [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html)